# jruby on rails - error when star server (rails s) command is used

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby, runtime-error

A error is thrown when

```
 rails s
```

command is used in the context of my project.

The following is my application settings:

1. JRuby (1.7.0.preview2)
2. Rails (3.2.8)
3. IBM DB2 Express C (1.01)
4. active-record-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2)

and this is the java error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION (0xc0000096) at pc=0x0155b803, pid=8552, tid=9692
#
# JRE version: 7.0_06-b24
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.2-b09 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0155b803
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0155b800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9692, stack(0x00030000,0x00230000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000096

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x0022e4cc, ECX=0x4b918881, EDX=0x0155be70
ESP=0x0022c31f, EBP=0x00000000, ESI=0x6e2dd981, EDI=0x0155b928
EIP=0x0155b803, EFLAGS=0x00010212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0022c31f)
0x0022c31f:   00000001 00000000 22c66800 22c31800
0x0022c32f:   1f22ce00 55b80005 4b520001 00000001
0x0022c33f:   00004c00 22c4e000 00189400 00124c00
0x0022c34f:   08000000 22c71411 22c36000 00004e00
0x0022c35f:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0022c36f:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0022c37f:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00010000
0x0022c38f:   00000000 00000000 00000300 00000700 

Instructions: (pc=0x0155b803)
0x0155b7e3:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0155b7f3:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 84 e6 4c
0x0155b803:   6e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 b4 55
0x0155b813:   01 b0 9e 55 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 4b 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x0022e4cc is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0155b800
ECX=0x4b918881 is an unknown value
EDX=0x0155be70 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0022c31f is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0155b800
EBP=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESI=0x6e2dd981 is an unknown value
EDI=0x0155b928 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00030000,0x00230000],  sp=0x0022c31f,  free space=2032k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0155b803

[I have cut this in order to post the question]

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x05bb2800 JavaThread "JRubyJIT-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7064, stack(0x06530000,0x06730000)]
  0x05bab800 JavaThread "JRubyJIT-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9600, stack(0x06330000,0x06530000)]
  0x041b5c00 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5368, stack(0x049a0000,0x04ba0000)]
  0x041b0400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10100, stack(0x047a0000,0x049a0000)]
  0x041af400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5224, stack(0x045a0000,0x047a0000)]
  0x041ac000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6284, stack(0x043a0000,0x045a0000)]
  0x014b7400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6280, stack(0x03fa0000,0x041a0000)]
  0x014b5800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10156, stack(0x03da0000,0x03fa0000)]
=>0x0155b800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9692, stack(0x00030000,0x00230000)]

Other Threads:
  0x014b4400 VMThread [stack: 0x03ba0000,0x03da0000] [id=6940]
  0x041d1800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x04ba0000,0x04da0000] [id=5440]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 637K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K,   4% used [0x14430000, 0x144636b8, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K,  84% used [0x14900000, 0x1496c0e0, 0x14980000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14880000, 0x14880000, 0x14900000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 7202K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  65% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f1d88c8, 0x1f1d8a00, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 13056K, used 12877K [0x33830000, 0x344f0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 13056K,  98% used [0x33830000, 0x344c37c8, 0x344c3800, 0x344f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)

Card table byte_map: [0x039c0000,0x03af0000] byte_map_base: 0x0391de80

Polling page: 0x003f0000

Code Cache  [0x01940000, 0x01b78000, 0x03940000)
 total_blobs=1432 nmethods=1170 adapters=195 free_code_cache=30499Kb largest_free_block=31231360

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2.590 Thread 0x041b0400 1168             org.jruby.lexer.yacc.RubyYaccLexer::rightParen (66 bytes)
Event: 2.591 Thread 0x041b0400 nmethod 1168 0x01b76148 code [0x01b76260, 0x01b764cc]
Event: 2.591 Thread 0x041b0400 1169             org.jruby.parser.Ruby19Parser$43::execute (13 bytes)
Event: 2.591 Thread 0x041b0400 nmethod 1169 0x01b76648 code [0x01b76740, 0x01b76800]
Event: 2.598 Thread 0x041b0400 1170             org.jruby.Ruby::getDummy (5 bytes)
Event: 2.598 Thread 0x041b0400 nmethod 1170 0x01b76908 code [0x01b76a00, 0x01b76a80]
Event: 2.600 Thread 0x041b0400 1171             org.jruby.RubyModule::iterateConstantNoConstMissing (55 bytes)
Event: 2.601 Thread 0x041b0400 nmethod 1171 0x01b76ac8 code [0x01b76bf0, 0x01b76d48]
Event: 2.601 Thread 0x041b0400 1172             java.nio.CharBuffer::arrayOffset (35 bytes)
Event: 2.601 Thread 0x041b0400 nmethod 1172 0x01b76f08 code [0x01b77020, 0x01b77198]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 1.702 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4928K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x14430000, 0x14880000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x14880000, 0x14900000, 0x14900000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14900000, 0x14900000, 0x14980000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 4557K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  41% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1ef436a8, 0x1ef43800, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 10858K [0x33830000, 0x34430000, 0x37830000)
   the space 12288K,  88% used [0x33830000, 0x342ca9d8, 0x342caa00, 0x34430000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
Event: 1.723 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 512K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x14430000, 0x14430000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x14900000, 0x14980000, 0x14980000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14880000, 0x14880000, 0x14900000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 6066K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  55% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f0bc850, 0x1f0bca00, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 10858K [0x33830000, 0x34430000, 0x37830000)
   the space 12288K,  88% used [0x33830000, 0x342ca9d8, 0x342caa00, 0x34430000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
}
Event: 2.033 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4928K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x14430000, 0x14880000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x14900000, 0x14980000, 0x14980000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14880000, 0x14880000, 0x14900000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 6066K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  55% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f0bc850, 0x1f0bca00, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12800K, used 12666K [0x33830000, 0x344b0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 12800K,  98% used [0x33830000, 0x3448e800, 0x3448e800, 0x344b0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
Event: 2.046 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=6 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 512K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x14430000, 0x14430000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x14880000, 0x14900000, 0x14900000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14900000, 0x14900000, 0x14980000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 6577K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  60% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f13c4e8, 0x1f13c600, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12800K, used 12666K [0x33830000, 0x344b0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 12800K,  98% used [0x33830000, 0x3448e800, 0x3448e800, 0x344b0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
}
Event: 2.247 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=6 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4928K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x14430000, 0x14880000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x14880000, 0x14900000, 0x14900000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14900000, 0x14900000, 0x14980000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 6577K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  60% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f13c4e8, 0x1f13c600, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12800K, used 12728K [0x33830000, 0x344b0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 12800K,  99% used [0x33830000, 0x3449e270, 0x3449e400, 0x344b0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
Event: 2.257 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 189K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x14430000, 0x14430000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K,  37% used [0x14900000, 0x1492f7d0, 0x14980000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14880000, 0x14880000, 0x14900000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 7071K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  64% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f1b7f38, 0x1f1b8000, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12800K, used 12728K [0x33830000, 0x344b0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 12800K,  99% used [0x33830000, 0x3449e270, 0x3449e400, 0x344b0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
}
Event: 2.427 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4605K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x14430000, 0x14880000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K,  37% used [0x14900000, 0x1492f7d0, 0x14980000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14880000, 0x14880000, 0x14900000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 7071K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  64% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f1b7f38, 0x1f1b8000, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12800K, used 12762K [0x33830000, 0x344b0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 12800K,  99% used [0x33830000, 0x344a6950, 0x344a6a00, 0x344b0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
Event: 2.431 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 300K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x14430000, 0x14430000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K,  58% used [0x14880000, 0x148cb268, 0x14900000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14900000, 0x14900000, 0x14980000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 7071K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  64% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f1b7f38, 0x1f1b8000, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12800K, used 12762K [0x33830000, 0x344b0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 12800K,  99% used [0x33830000, 0x344a6950, 0x344a6a00, 0x344b0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
}
Event: 2.593 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=8 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4716K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x14430000, 0x14880000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K,  58% used [0x14880000, 0x148cb268, 0x14900000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14900000, 0x14900000, 0x14980000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 7071K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  64% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f1b7f38, 0x1f1b8000, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 13056K, used 12830K [0x33830000, 0x344f0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 13056K,  98% used [0x33830000, 0x344b7ba8, 0x344b7c00, 0x344f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
Event: 2.598 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=9 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 432K [0x14430000, 0x14980000, 0x1ead0000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x14430000, 0x14430000, 0x14880000)
  from space 512K,  84% used [0x14900000, 0x1496c0e0, 0x14980000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x14880000, 0x14880000, 0x14900000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 7202K [0x1ead0000, 0x1f580000, 0x33830000)
   the space 10944K,  65% used [0x1ead0000, 0x1f1d88c8, 0x1f1d8a00, 0x1f580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 13056K, used 12830K [0x33830000, 0x344f0000, 0x37830000)
   the space 13056K,  98% used [0x33830000, 0x344b7ba8, 0x344b7c00, 0x344f0000)
    ro space 10240K,  45% used [0x37830000, 0x37cb4988, 0x37cb4a00, 0x38230000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38230000, 0x388b8030, 0x388b8200, 0x38e30000)
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 2.514 Thread 0x05bab800 Threw 0x146c0b58 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.514 Thread 0x05bab800 Threw 0x146c3420 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.525 Thread 0x05bb2800 Threw 0x14716cf0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.526 Thread 0x05bb2800 Threw 0x14719ae0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.528 Thread 0x0155b800 Threw 0x147121c0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.528 Thread 0x0155b800 Threw 0x147159f0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.529 Thread 0x0155b800 Threw 0x147446b8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.529 Thread 0x0155b800 Threw 0x14745148 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.529 Thread 0x0155b800 Threw 0x14748978 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166
Event: 2.529 Thread 0x0155b800 Threw 0x147496a8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u6\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1166

Events (10 events):
Event: 2.616 loading class 0x042b79b0 done
Event: 2.616 loading class 0x0429f000 done
Event: 2.616 loading class 0x042a2ff0
Event: 2.616 loading class 0x042a2ff0 done
Event: 2.617 loading class 0x05b0a4f8
Event: 2.617 loading class 0x05b0a4f8 done
Event: 2.617 Executing VM operation: Deoptimize
Event: 2.618 Executing VM operation: Deoptimize done
Event: 2.618 Executing VM operation: Deoptimize
Event: 2.618 Executing VM operation: Deoptimize done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00456000     C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview2\bin\jruby.exe
0x77a00000 - 0x77b3c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x76020000 - 0x760f4000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75c70000 - 0x75cba000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x777a0000 - 0x77840000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.DLL
0x77b50000 - 0x77bfc000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x77c10000 - 0x77c29000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x76100000 - 0x761a1000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77450000 - 0x77519000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x77520000 - 0x7756e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77b40000 - 0x77b4a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x77230000 - 0x772cd000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x76000000 - 0x7601f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x761b0000 - 0x7627c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x684c0000 - 0x68532000     C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview2\bin\jruby.dll
0x77570000 - 0x775a5000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x771f0000 - 0x771f6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x6e230000 - 0x6e57c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x6f130000 - 0x6f137000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x739c0000 - 0x739f2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75ff0000 - 0x75ff5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x77e40000 - 0x77efe000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\MSVCR100.dll
0x59220000 - 0x5922c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x59050000 - 0x59070000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\java.dll
0x558b0000 - 0x558c3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x75640000 - 0x75656000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x753b0000 - 0x753eb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x751b0000 - 0x751c7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75b90000 - 0x75b9b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x75b10000 - 0x75b1c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x509c0000 - 0x509d4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\net.dll
0x75600000 - 0x7563c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x755f0000 - 0x755f6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x74540000 - 0x74550000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x6ead0000 - 0x6eae0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x6eab0000 - 0x6eac2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x754c0000 - 0x75504000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x6eaa0000 - 0x6eaa8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x6ea70000 - 0x6ea97000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x76280000 - 0x762d7000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x750e0000 - 0x750e5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x74290000 - 0x742ac000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x74280000 - 0x74287000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x6ea60000 - 0x6ea66000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x74180000 - 0x741b8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x55400000 - 0x5540f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x051f0000 - 0x0520b000     C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview2\lib\native\i386-Windows\jffi-1.2.dll
0x76480000 - 0x770ca000     C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll
0x775b0000 - 0x7770c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x75ac0000 - 0x75b0c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x508b0000 - 0x5099b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djdk.home= -Djruby.home=C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview2 -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=cmd.exe -Djffi.boot.library.path=C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview2\lib\native\i386-Windows;C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview2\lib\native\x86_64-Windows -Xmx500m -Xss2048k -Djruby.memory.max=500m -Djruby.stack.max=2048k -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview2\lib\jruby.jar 
java_command: org.jruby.Main
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\sqlj.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\common.jar
PATH=C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview2\bin;c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\windows live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\110\dts\binn\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\110\tools\binn\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\110\tools\binn\managementstudio\;c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\common7\ide\privateassemblies\;c:\program files\windows live\shared;c:\program files\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL
USERNAME=Joro
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 3145272k(853168k free), swap 6288788k(2541460k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.2-b09) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_06-b24), built on Aug  9 2012 23:02:07 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Wed Aug 29 21:06:00 2012
elapsed time: 2 seconds
```

Has anyone got idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried: "jruby -S rails s"?

Comment: @Luke, again the server starts but the error is thrown. Could you advice something?

Comment: could it be due to jruby is a preview ?! I had a lot of problems with preview 1 so I change back to 1.6.7, could you try running it with jruby 167 ?

Comment: @M.Octavio What is the easiest way to change the current version with older one?

Comment: RVM does jRuby I think. You could try using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to read the dump, but I can tell you that JVM is crashing.

Try:

1. A different version of JVM; Java 6 u35, or Java 7 u7.
2. Disabling JIT (`jruby -Xcompile.mode=OFF`)
3. Give more memory to JRuby than 500MB.

It could also be some bug with JDBC adapter, but I am not familiar with the code base. Whatever the case, it is best to come up with a minimal test case where the problem is observed. (Ideally, this won't involve Rails.)

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestions and let you know what happened.

Comment: executing (jruby -Xcompile.mode=OFF) does not seem to do anything - I get no result. I try to give more space to JRuby using the following code - (jruby -S -JXms512m -J-Xmx1024m blog) where blog is my project, but it is saying that there is no such directory. Could you advice?