# How to update java version used by Jruby?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, version, jruby, upgrade

I am really lost in these Java things. The [latest java versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) are announced in the Oracle website.

[image]

And as you can see from the next screenshot, my current version is:

[image]

Then, why is my Jruby not using this version and how can I force it to use the latest version installed on my machine?

[image]

The reason I want to use the newest versions is that I have some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184111/jruby-on-rails-error-when-star-server-rails-s-command-is-used) with

```
rails -s
```

command and one of the things that I have been advised was to upgrade my Java version.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `JAVA_HOME` to the location of your Java directory:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ jruby -v 
jruby 1.7.0.preview2 (1.9.3p203) 2012-09-13 c35a3e1 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_24-b24 [linux-amd64]
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ jruby -v 
jruby 1.7.0.preview2 (1.9.3p203) 2012-09-13 c35a3e1 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_07-b30 [linux-amd64]
```

Comment: I am sorry. I should have mentioned that I am using Windows 7. Could you reverse this?

Comment: @Joro On Windows I believe you also need to add the Java `bin` folder to the `PATH` system variable as well as setting `JAVA_HOME` so that jruby-launcher can find the `jvm.dll`.

Comment: Thank you. As soon as I try this, I will inform you what happened.

Comment: On my Windows 7 computer I was also forced to reboot after changing the "PATH" variable.